# Facing Invalid Session ID issue in selenium Web driver Using TestNG frame work

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

```
    package automation;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login {
    public String baseURL="https://learn.stagingaia.com/login";
    public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
        public void setBaseUrl(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://Selenium//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void titleverification() {
        String expectedtitle="Acadify";
        String actualtitle=driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle,expectedtitle);
    }
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void ValidCrdentials() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("acadifysuperadmin@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Password@123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String ExpectedHeading="Dashboard";
        String actulHeading=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/h2/span")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(actulHeading, ExpectedHeading);
    }
    @Test(priority=3)
    public void InvalidEmail() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("example@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Password@123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String ExpectedEmailError="Dashboard";
        String ActuaEmailError=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(ActuaEmailError, ExpectedEmailError);
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void EndSession() {
        driver.close();
    }
    
}
```

### I am using this code but it is showing that result.

```
PASSED: EndSession
PASSED: ValidCrdentials
PASSED: titleverification
FAILED: InvalidEmail
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: **invalid session id**
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [4002147c7121449294c404b500c276b5, findElement {using=xpath, value=/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 109.0.5414.120, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604da..., userDataDir: C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57842}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:57842/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 109.0.5414.120, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 4002147c7121449294c404b500c276b5
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:535)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:351)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:343)
    at automation.Login.InvalidEmail(Login.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Default test
    Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. 
Good to ask question in the community channel. But can you pls add what all you have tried and system and components details will help ppl to help you quickly to resolve your error/question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods available in the WebDriver interface `quit()` and `close()`.

- `driver.quit()`: The `quit()` method quits the driver, ends the session and closes all associated browser windows opened during a test whether the test fails or passes.
- `driver.close()`: The `close()` method closes the currently focused window, quitting the driver if the current window is the only open window. If there are no windows open, it will error out.

In `quit()` if you try to execute any statement, sessionID=null will be sent and you will get exception - `Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?`

In `close()`, random sessionID(only one) will be created and maintained for entire session. After execution of `close()`, session will be invalid or expired.

In short `quit()` the session is `null` and in `close()` session id is `invalid`.

To fix your error, try this code.

```
@AfterTest
public void EndSession() {
    if (driver == null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```